# Which is best for a medium to enterprise level web app, PhP vs Java?

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails

Now before At the risk of getting this subject closed I just need to resolve an issue between I and the other developer consultant.
We're tasked with redeveloping a web app that does some employee management and financial book-keeping of sorts. I'm no web technologies expert but I believe in subscribing to the MVC type development methodology. So I have been looking at the tool of choice to get the job done for a while now. The other guys is championing PhP as a tool of choice, however I have reservations because using php will not really allow for the good practice of MVC. I have been looking at other alternatives and have heard Ruby on Rails, Wicket, Django e.t.c. mentioned. My only objection with PhP is that the business code is tied to the view code.

This is an edit.
I am currently looking at the ruby on rails site. Does anyone have a comment as to the suitability of this web technology/framework for medium (to possible enterprise) level web app development?

Comment: we don't know your complete business requirements, so how can we prescribe a solution technology for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going about your evaluation incorrectly.

Your stack depends on at least a few factors:

- Developer familiarity/learning curve
- Community volume
- Licensing
- Scalability
- Server availability/configuration
- Supportability
- Maintainability

There are probably dozens of subtle factors that will contribute to the total cost of ownership of your webapp.

Every language/framework you mention will solve your problems. PHP has MVC frameworks like CakePHP (which is modeled after Rails). Python has Django. Java has SpringMVC/Roo. Groovy has Grails. Ruby has Rails.

Every one of these adhere to MVC principles and contain RAD tools (i.e. rapid development), so in my opinion, you need to chart and evaluate the other factors because unless you have a preference or are forced to conform to executive mandate, you could just as easily pick a stack out of a hat.

Comment: I still consider myself new to the web development arena but these are considerations I'm taking into account before settling on the tool of choice. I just needed to ask the community for advice and opinion to sort of crystallise the list.

Comment: Makes sense. My list would include what I mentioned in my answer in this order: Java/SpringMVC, Groovy/Grails, Ruby/Rails, PHP/CakePHP, Python/Django...but that's based on my preference and familiarity.

Answer (score 2):

[Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com) is the one of the most lightweight([fast](http://talks.php.net/show/froscon08/30)) PHP framework which uses [MVC](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html). You could use both languages(PHP/Java). You could even use both languages at the same time. Just get programming ;)

For example on Java I was impressed with the simplicity of [Play! framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

Comment: We use Kohana which came from the code igniter base and it's breen great for HMVC.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks. I'd never even heard of HMVC until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, PHP is just a programming language, is up to the programmer to turn things into good or bad ones. Ruby On Rails bring the MVC pattern to the web scope but that doesn't mean that Ruby is better than other languages to make web development with MVC in mind. And the same apply for Java vs PHP, in fact since PHP5
support a similar set of OOP constructs that Java, you can do easily your own controller factory supporting dependency injection...

Now, Almost any major programming language today have at least a good MVC implementation, with good meaning: testable, database independent, extensible and backend by an strong community. You can view this
Wikipedia page to see a list of implementations.

So if you need to rewrite a web site using MVC in mind (more soon than later), I think your tool of choice must be determined by the background of the programmers you have avalaible. In case of doubts run an small demo with the options you have, is the best way to tell.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that it's up to the proverbial carpenter to use his tools effectively, however I guess I should've been clearer that I'd like to use a tool with OOP principles intrinsically embedded in it's architecture. I guess I consider this to be a good foundation to the MVC methodology, however not essential. I do like the ease of use of and simplicity PhP but sometimes oversimplification can lead to complexity in certain scenarios.